# Mathematica: branch points for real roots of polynomial

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am doing a brute force search for "gradient extremals" on the following example function

```
fv[{x_, y_}] = ((y - (x/4)^2)^2 + 1/(4 (1 + (x - 1)^2)))/2;
```

This involves finding the following zeros

```
gecond = With[{g = D[fv[{x, y}], {{x, y}}], h = D[fv[{x, y}], {{x, y}, 2}]},
 g.RotationMatrix[Pi/2].h.g == 0]
```

Which `Reduce` happily does for me:

```
geyvals = y /. Cases[List@ToRules@Reduce[gecond, {x, y}], {y -> _}];
```

`geyvals` is the three roots of a cubic polynomial, but the expression is a bit large to put here.

Now to my question: For different values of `x`, different numbers of these roots are real, and I would like to pick out the values of `x` where the solutions branch in order to piece together the gradient extremals along the valley floor (of `fv`). In the present case, since the polynomial is only cubic, I could probably do it by hand -- but I am looking for a simple way of having Mathematica do it for me?

**Edit**: To clarify: The gradient extremals stuff is just background -- and a simple way to set up a hard problem. I am not so interested in the specific solution to this problem as in a general hand-off way of spotting the branch points for polynomial roots. Have added an answer below with a working approach.

**Edit 2**: Since it seems that the actual problem is much more fun than root branching: rcollyer suggests using `ContourPlot` directly on `gecond` to get the gradient extremals. To make this complete we need to separate valleys and ridges, which is done by looking at the eigenvalue of the Hessian perpendicular to the gradient. Putting a check for "valleynes" in as a `RegionFunction` we are left with only the valley line:

```
valleycond = With[{
    g = D[fv[{x, y}], {{x, y}}], 
    h = D[fv[{x, y}], {{x, y}, 2}]},
  g.RotationMatrix[Pi/2].h.RotationMatrix[-Pi/2].g >= 0];
gbuf["gevalley"]=ContourPlot[gecond // Evaluate, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -.5, 1.2},
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Evaluate@valleycond], 
   PlotPoints -> 41];
```

Which gives just the valley floor line. Including some contours and the saddle point:

```
fvSaddlept = {x, y} /. First@Solve[Thread[D[fv[{x, y}], {{x, y}}] == {0, 0}]]
gbuf["contours"] = ContourPlot[fv[{x, y}],
   {x, -2, 4}, {y, -.7, 1.5}, PlotRange -> {0, 1/2},
   Contours -> fv@fvSaddlept (Range[6]/3 - .01),
   PlotPoints -> 41, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ContourShading -> None];
gbuf["saddle"] = Graphics[{Red, Point[fvSaddlept]}];
Show[gbuf /@ {"contours", "saddle", "gevalley"}]
```

We end up with a plot like this:

[image: Contour plot of fv with the valley line superposed]

Comment: I did this by hand a few times, so +1. Hope someone find a way.

Comment: @belisarius. Exactly -- have done it a few times, and it is a nuisance. This tim I can't be bothered since I really only need the result for a plot where, to be completely honest, a simple guess would look fine... Let's hope somebody has a clever idea :)

Comment: @Janus, forgive my ignorance, but how does `gecond` give you the extremals? I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: @Janus, nevermind. I found a paper that discusses them, specifically eqn 3.3 of http://www.springerlink.com/content/1432-881x/69/4/ matches `gecond` exactly.

Comment: @rcollyer: Thanks for the reference: I have hit a few reaction potential articles, but this issue seems to be a nice collection. It's actually trivial once you realize that the GE condition is equivalent to requiring the gradient to be an eigenvector of the curvature. I actually came from that direction and only found the work on 'gradient extremals' after having done quite a bit of rediscovery. J. Math. Phys. 23p732 has a nice coordinate-free discussion, but the topic goes back to Maxwell and Cayley :)

Comment: @janus, if you were just interested in the gradient extremals and didn't care much for their formulas, you could just `ContourPlot[g.RotationMatrix[Pi/2].h.g == 0]`.

Comment: @janus, as a clarification are you interested in the branch points, or would a method to generate (at least an implicit) formula for the real roots be sufficient?

Comment: @rcollyer, No I don't need the branch points. I assume the implicit method is the one you have added to your answer? I'm still trying to understand your answer -- will comment below.

Comment: @janus, I'm trying to reproduce the contours in your plot. From the looks of them, I assume you're using some `RegionFunction`, what was it?

Comment: @rcollyer Sorry -- offline for a while. I think it was just a `PlotRange`, I'll include the full plot code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this (belatedly) helps, but it seems you are interested in discriminant points, that is, where both polynomial and derivative (wrt y) vanish. You can solve this system for {x,y} and throw away complex solutions as below.

```
fv[{x_, y_}] = ((y - (x/4)^2)^2 + 1/(4 (1 + (x - 1)^2)))/2;

gecond = With[{g = D[fv[{x, y}], {{x, y}}], 
   h = D[fv[{x, y}], {{x, y}, 2}]}, g.RotationMatrix[Pi/2].h.g]

In[14]:= Cases[{x, y} /. 
  NSolve[{gecond, D[gecond, y]} == 0, {x, y}], {_Real, _Real}]

Out[14]= {{-0.0158768, -15.2464}, {1.05635, -0.963629}, {1., 
  0.0625}, {1., 0.0625}}
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! You are right, these are exactly the points I was chasing -- catches both the branch-points and root crossings: For a parametrized polynomial P(a,x), the a-values where the roots branch or cross are exactly the a-values with a multiple root, so that P(a,x)==0 and  dP(a,x)/dx=0.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to plot the result then use [`StreamPlot[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamPlot.html) on the gradients:

```
grad = D[fv[{x, y}], {{x, y}}];
StreamPlot[grad, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
           RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, fv[{x, y}] < 1],
           StreamScale -> 1]
```

You may have to fiddle around with the plot's precision, StreamStyle, and the RegionFunction to get it perfect. Especially useful would be using the solution for the valley floor to seed `StreamPoints` programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, Timo. The problem with streamplot is that the 'fall-lines', as the resulting lines are known, are mathematically guaranteed to diverge from the stationary paths (the gradient extremes), see e.g. J. Math. Phys. 23p732. Especially so in the interesting regions :) Also: I have a nice algorithm for finding the valley -- this question was more about the root branching.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**: see below.

I'd approach this first by visualizing the imaginary parts of the roots:

[image: plot of the imaginary parts of the roots]

This tells you three things immediately:  1) the first root is always real, 2) the second two are the conjugate pairs, and 3) there is a small region near zero in which all three are real.  Additionally, note that the exclusions only got rid of the singular point at `x=0`, and we can see why when we zoom in:

[image: zoom in of above photo with x between 0 and 1.5]

We can then use the `EvalutionMonitor` to generate the list of roots directly:

```
Map[Module[{f, fcn = #1}, 
            f[x_] := Im[fcn];
            Reap[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1.5}, 
                  Exclusions -> {True, f[x] == 1, f[x] == -1}, 
                  EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, f[x]}][[2, 1]] // 
            SortBy[#, First] &];]
   ]&, geyvals]
```

(Note, the `Part` specification is a little odd, `Reap` returns a `List` of what is sown as the second item in a `List`, so this results in a nested list.  Also, `Plot` doesn't sample the points in a straightforward manner, so `SortBy` is needed.) There may be a more elegant route to determine where the last two roots become complex, but since their imaginary parts are piecewise continuous, it just seemed easier to brute force it.

**Edit**: Since you've mentioned that you want an automatic method for generating where some of the roots become complex, I've been exploring what happens when you substitute in `y -> p + I q`.  Now this assumes that `x` is real, but you've already done that in your solution.  Specifically, I do the following

```
In[1] := poly = g.RotationMatrix[Pi/2].h.g /. {y -> p + I q} // ComplexExpand;
In[2] := {pr,pi} = poly /. Complex[a_, b_] :> a + z b & // CoefficientList[#, z] & //
         Simplify[#, {x, p, q} \[Element] Reals]&;
```

where the second step allows me to isolate the real and imaginary parts of the equation and simplify them independent of each other.  Doing this same thing with the generic 2D polynomial, `f + d x + a x^2 + e y + 2 c x y + b y^2`, but making both `x` and `y` complex; I noted that `Im[poly] = Im[x] D[poly, Im[x]] + Im[y] D[poly,[y]]`, and this may hold for your equation, also.  By making `x` real, the imaginary part of `poly` becomes `q` times some function of `x`, `p`, and `q`.  So, setting `q=0` always gives `Im[poly] == 0`.  But, that does not tell us anything new.  However, if we

```
In[3] := qvals = Cases[List@ToRules@RReduce[ pi == 0 && q != 0, {x,p,q}], 
          {q -> a_}:> a];
```

we get several formulas for `q` involving `x` and `p`.  For some values of `x` and `p`, those formulas may be imaginary, and we can use `Reduce` to determine where `Re[qvals] == 0`.  In other words, we want the "imaginary" part of `y` to be real and this can be accomplished by allowing `q` to be zero or purely imaginary.  Plotting the region where `Re[q]==0` and overlaying the gradient extremal lines via

```
With[{rngs = Sequence[{x,-2,2},{y,-10,10}]},
Show@{
 RegionPlot[Evaluate[Thread[Re[qvals]==0]/.p-> y], rngs],
 ContourPlot[g.RotationMatrix[Pi/2].h.g==0,rngs 
      ContourStyle -> {Darker@Red,Dashed}]}]
```

gives

[image: x-y plot showing gradient extremals and region where there are 3 real roots]

which confirms the regions in the first two plots showing the 3 real roots.

Comment: I like the idea about using the built-in logic of Plot to zoom in on the key points. Playing around with it, it seems to take some post processing to spot the sharp bends.

Comment: +1 for massive effort! And a tickmark for simply contour plotting `gecond`: it is not strictly an answer to the root branching -- but it is a clever solution to my actual problem. Have added some extra background on valleys/ridges to my question.

Comment: @janus, If I knew I'd get the checkmark for plotting the extremals, I would have done it much, much sooner. :)

Comment: I agree it's not quite kosher to checkmark for a not-strictly-an-answer, but it doesn't seem as if anybody else is working on the root branching and I really never thought about just doing the ContourPlot, so it did solve my actual problem...

Comment: @Janus, don't worry about it. He nailed it while Iwas just taking a stab in the dark. so, not a worry.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up trying myself since the goal really was to do it 'hands off'. I'll leave the question open for a good while to see if anybody finds a better way.

The code below uses bisection to bracket the points where `CountRoots` changes value. This works for my case (spotting the singularity at x=0 is pure luck):

```
In[214]:= findRootBranches[Function[x, Evaluate@geyvals[[1, 1]]], {-5, 5}]
Out[214]= {{{-5., -0.0158768}, 1}, {{-0.0158768, -5.96046*10^-9}, 3}, {{0., 0.}, 2}, {{5.96046*10^-9, 1.05635}, 3}, {{1.05635, 5.}, 1}}
```

Implementation:

```
Options[findRootBranches] = {
   AccuracyGoal -> $MachinePrecision/2,
   "SamplePoints" -> 100};

findRootBranches::usage = 
  "findRootBranches[f,{x0,x1}]: Find the the points in [x0,x1] \
  where the number of real roots of a polynomial changes.
  Returns list of {<interval>,<root count>} pairs.
  f: Real -> Polynomial as pure function, e.g f=Function[x,#^2-x&]." ; 

findRootBranches[f_, {xa_, xb_}, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {bisect, y, rootCount, acc = 10^-OptionValue[AccuracyGoal]},
  rootCount[x_] := {x, CountRoots[f[x][y], y]};

  (* Define a ecursive bisector w/ automatic subdivision *)
  bisect[{{x1_, n1_}, {x2_, n2_}} /; Abs[x1 - x2] > acc] := 
   Module[{x3, n3},
    {x3, n3} = rootCount[(x1 + x2)/2];
    Which[
     n1 == n3, bisect[{{x3, n3}, {x2, n2}}],
     n2 == n3, bisect[{{x1, n1}, {x3, n3}}],
     True, {bisect[{{x1, n1}, {x3, n3}}], 
      bisect[{{x3, n3}, {x2, n2}}]}]];

  (* Find initial brackets and bisect *)
  Module[{xn, samplepoints, brackets},
   samplepoints = N@With[{sp = OptionValue["SamplePoints"]},
      If[NumberQ[sp], xa + (xb - xa) Range[0, sp]/sp, Union[{xa, xb}, sp]]];
   (* Start by counting roots at initial sample points *)
   xn = rootCount /@ samplepoints;
   (* Then, identify and refine the brackets *)
   brackets = Flatten[bisect /@ 
      Cases[Partition[xn, 2, 1], {{_, a_}, {_, b_}} /; a != b]];
   (* Reinclude the endpoints and partition into same-rootcount segments: *)
   With[{allpts = Join[{First@xn}, 
       Flatten[brackets /. bisect -> List, 2], {Last@xn}]},
    {#1, Last[#2]} & @@@ Transpose /@ Partition[allpts, 2]
    ]]]
```

Comment: -1: This doesn't spot the cases where two roots cross each other.

Comment: Ok, so finding the precise location of a root crossing is very doable, since Mathematica can do series expansions of root objects: `x/.First@Solve[0==Normal@Quiet@Series[r1-r2,{x,x0,1}],x]`. Now, how to spot potential crossings is not so obvious...